Filtrar de manera multiple varias columnas con PHP y Datatable
Tengo la siguiente problematica.
Tengo 2 tablas una llamada area y otra llamada cargo la cual ya las tengo relacionada
pero la idea es que en el datatable al escribir en el search Judicial (que seria un Area), aparecen todos los registros que pertenecen a judicial pero quisiera escribir Juez al lado de judicial para que me traiga solo ese registro pero en el momento que doy espacio ya se pierden los registros.
estoy usando CodeIgniter 3 y DataTable Jquery Ajax el codigo es el siguiente:
class Cargos extends CI_Model { 
    var $table = 'cargos';
    var $column_order = array('cargo.nombre_cargo'); 
    var $column_search = array('area.nombre_area','cargo.nombre_cargo');        
    var $order = array('cargo.id_cargo' => 'desc');

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_data($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('area.nombre_area,cargo.nombre_cargo');
        $this->db->from($this->table.' cargo');
        $this->db->where('cargo.id_cargo',$id);
        $this->db->join('areas area', 'area.id_area = cargo.id_area');
        return $this->db->get()->row();  
    }
    
    private function _get_datatables_query()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->table.' cargo');
        $this->db->join('areas area', 'area.id_area = cargo.id_area');
       /*  $this->db->where('a.id_area','b.id_area'); */
    
        $i = 0;
    
        foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {
                
                if($i===0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                    $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
            }
            $i++;
        }
        
        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        } 
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }

    public function get_datatables()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function count_filtered()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }
}

y mi JS es este
$('#cargos-table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ordering": false,
        "responsive": true,
        "lengthChange": true,
        "autoWidth": false,
        language: {
            "url": url_base + "public/assets/Spanish.json"
        },
        destroy: true,
        lengthMenu: [
            [10, 25, 50],
            [10, 25, 50]
        ],
        drawCallback: function (settings) {
            $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        },

        "ajax": {
            "url": url_base + 'cargo/datatables',
            "type": "POST"
        },
    });


tal vez necesitaras modificar la logica de busqueda en _get_datatables_query en el modelo de codeigniter puede ser que el problema que nos dices ocurre porque el $_POST['search']['value'] toma toda la cadena de busqueda completa (por ejemplo, "Judicial Juez") y la aplica como un unico sentido en la busqueda LIKE, lo que no va a correr si estas tratando de buscar terminos separados en diferentes columnas.
vamos a ajustar _get_datatables_query  y tratar de explicar como va a funcionar:
se divide la cadena de busqueda en palabras individuales utilizando explode(' ', $search_value) .. ahora para cada termino de busqueda abrimos un subgrupo de condiciones OR para aplicar el LIKE en cada columna definida en column_search ahora usamos group_start() y group_end() para agrupar las condiciones OR paraque realice la busqueda en todas las columnas para cada termino que vas a buscar... ahora bien se supone quecuando escribas "Judicial Juez" correra datos contengan "Judicial" en alguna de las columnas de busqueda y "Juez" en esas mismas columnas y deberia darte los registros y a tu JS no necesitas moverle nadita todo lo recargamos en los ajustes antes mencionados
private function _get_datatables_query()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->table . ' cargo');
    $this->db->join('areas area', 'area.id_area = cargo.id_area');

    $search_value = $_POST['search']['value'];

    if ($search_value) {
        // aqui se divide en palabras separadas por espacios la busqueda
        $search_terms = explode(' ', $search_value);

        $this->db->group_start(); // aca las condiciones OR le abrimos un grupito

        foreach ($search_terms as $term) {
            $this->db->group_start(); // aca el subgrupo
            foreach ($this->column_search as $item) {
                $this->db->or_like($item, $term);
            }
            $this->db->group_end(); // cierras el subgrupo
        }

        $this->db->group_end(); // cerramos el grupo general
    }

    if (isset($_POST['order'])) {
        $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
    } else if (isset($this->order)) {
        $order = $this->order;
        $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
    }
}

espero sea de ayuda, si no vemos que hacemos despues..
